# ProcessBuilder fails on command that includes local environment variable

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I can execute usual commands on Linux, wrapped by the processBuilder. But I'm currently trying to run the minecraft server like in the following example, with some variable set before the command, and it fails with an exception.

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server");
processBuilder.directory(MC_PAL_LOCATION_DIR.toFile());
process = processBuilder.start();
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server" (in directory "/home/user/Desktop/minecraft_bedrock_server_t"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at controller.Server.startMinecraftServer(Server.java:91)
    at controller.Server.start(Server.java:58)
    at Bootstrapper.bootServer(Bootstrapper.java:67)
    at Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:30)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 4 more
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.ConsoleInput.run(ConsoleInput.java:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any possibility to use the processBuilder for such commands? The command works if I paste it directly to the terminal.

Link to server: https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock/

Command: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server`

Comment: I *think* BeanShell is more geared towards this type of sysadmin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use bash shell commands like that without bash. But you can manipulate the environment yourself programmatically. Like,

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./bedrock_server");
processBuilder.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", ".");
processBuilder.directory(MC_PAL_LOCATION_DIR.toFile());
process = processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: Lol this is embarrassing, so close but I didn't figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As @ElliottFrisch pointed out, you cannot use shell command without bash, therefore you either add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to environment map or execute bash:

```
    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c",  "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./bedrock_server");
    processBuilder.directory(MC_PAL_LOCATION_DIR.toFile());
    process = processBuilder.start();
```